# MediatR Abstract Base Command

Tags: c#, abstract-class, mediatr

I have a scenario, where I would like to Enable/Disable a PurchaseOrderItem

So I have written two separate Command and commandHandlers. Ideally I have to create base abstract class and need to move my logic to one place.

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

Commands:

```cs
enum CommandType {
  Disable,
  Enable
}

class EnableCommand : IRequest {

}

class DisableCommand : IRequest {

}

class CommonCommand : IRequest {
  public CommandType Type {get; set;}
}
```

Handlers:

```cs
class EnableCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<EnableCommand> {
  private readonly IMediator _mediator;
  public EnableCommandHandler(IMediator mediator) {
    _mediator = mediator;
  }

  public async Task Handle(EnableCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    await _mediator.Send(new CommonCommand {Type = CommandType.Enable});
  } 
}

class DisableCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<DisableCommand> {
  private readonly IMediator _mediator;
  public EnableCommandHandler(IMediator mediator) {
    _mediator = mediator;
  }

  public async Task Handle(DisableCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    await _mediator.Send(new CommonCommand {Type = CommandType.Disable});
  } 
}

class CommonCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<CommonCommand> {
  private readonly IMediator _mediator;
  public EnableCommandHandler(IMediator mediator) {
    _mediator = mediator;
  }

  public async Task Handle(CommonCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    ... // some common logic
    switch(command.Type) {
      ... // some specific logic
    }
  } 
}
```

And if you don't want to create 3 handlers you can create one for all this commands:

```cs
class CommonCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<EnableCommand> , IRequestHandler<DisableCommand>, IRequestHandler<CommonCommand> {
    public async Task Handle(EnableCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        await Handle(new CommonCommand {Type = CommandType.Enable});
    } 
    public async Task Handle(DisableCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        await Handle(new CommonCommand {Type = CommandType.Disable});
    } 

    public async Task Handle(CommonCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        ... // some common logic
        switch(command.Type) {
            ... // some specific logic
        }
    } 
}
```

For last options you actually don't need `CommonCommand` as `IRequest`. So idea is to re-use handlers.

Comment: Thank you @batangaming. 
Is there any other way to achieve using abstract command and handlers?

Comment: I guess it won't work as you want and really I don't have answer on your question

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with one command/handler.

```
public enum PurchaseOrderStatus
{
    Enabled,
    Disabled
}

public class TogglePurchaseOrderItemStatusCommand : IRequest
{
    public PurchaseOrderStatus Status { get; }

    public TogglePurchaseOrderItemStatusCommand(PurchaseOrderStatus status)
    {
        Status = status;
    }
}

public class TogglePurchaseOrderItemCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<TogglePurchaseOrderItemCommand>
{
    public Task<Unit> Handle(TogglePurchaseOrderItemCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //Execute Logic Here Based on request.Status
    }
}
```